# Typescript difference between arrays

Tags: arrays, typescript

I'm new to Typescript and I'm declaring arrays like this:

```
variable1: MyType[];
```

Then I realized that another guy in my group is declaring them like this:

```
variable2: [MyType];
```

I never saw something similiar to the last one in any other language. I asked him what was the difference and he didn't know the answer.

If I try to assign `variable1` to `variable2`, Typescript complains that they are different types and cannot be assigned to each other.

So, my question is, what exactly is the type of `variable2`?

This may be a pretty stupid/simple question that should be easily found on Google, but I don't even know how to call the `variable2` object type to search for it...

Comment: Haskell uses the second form, btw. Fun fact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
variable1: MyType[];
```

Is an array of `MyType`

```
variable2: [MyType];
```

is a unary [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) containing a single `MyType`

The first is a collection, the second is not. If we were using numbers, `variable1` would accept values of `[n1,n2,...]` while `variable2` would accept only `[n]`